# Find BAILEY's BLUE BANDANNA

Tags: sql, postgresql

Imagine dance teams (of varying size) can choose one or more outfits and each outfit can have one or more items. All members of a team must have all same outfits and all the items of each outfit, i.e., incomplete outfits are bad -- we want to find those bad outfits.

The tables below define two teams: APPLE and BANANA. Team APPLE has 3 members, team BANANA two members. The APPLEs have chosen a single outfit which has a single item, the YELLOW PANTSUIT outfit, naturally a crowd favorite. Team BANANA have two outfits: RED, and BLUE; but, BAILEY is missing the BANDANNAS item for the BLUE outfit. Awkward.

Let's get BAILEY out of trouble. Create a query to find missing items in the outfits chosen by the teams.

Thanks to @Brits for the SQL below:

**Teams and team-members:**

```
CREATE TABLE team (
    id   int unique,
    name text
);
INSERT INTO team (id, name)
VALUES (1, 'APPLE'),
       (2, 'BANANA');

CREATE TABLE team_member (
    id      int unique,
    name    text,
    team_id int references team (id)
);
INSERT INTO team_member (id, name, team_id)
VALUES (1, 'ADAM', 2),
       (2, 'BAILEY', 2),
       (3, 'CATE', 1),
       (4, 'DAVE', 1),
       (5, 'ERIN', 1);
```

**Outfits and outfit items:**

```
CREATE TABLE outfit (
    id   int unique,
    name text
);
INSERT INTO outfit (id, name)
VALUES (1, 'RED'),
       (2, 'YELLOW'),
       (3, 'BLUE');

CREATE TABLE outfit_item (
    id        int unique,
    name      text,
    outfit_id int references outfit (id)
);
INSERT INTO outfit_item (id, name, outfit_id)
VALUES (1, 'SHORTS', 1),
       (2, 'SHIRT', 1),
       (3, 'PANTSUIT', 2),
       (4, 'BANDANNA', 3),
       (5, 'HAT', 3);
```

**Team member outfit items:**

```
CREATE TABLE member_item (
    member_id int references team_member (id),
    item_id   int references outfit_item (id)
);

INSERT INTO member_item (member_id, item_id)
VALUES (1, 1),
       (1, 2),
       (1, 4),
       (1, 5),
       (2, 1),
       (2, 2),
       (2, 5),
       (3, 3),
       (4, 3),
       (5, 3);
```

Team APPLE's members all have the YELLOW PANTSUIT outfit so the APPLEs are ready to rumble.

Team BANANA chose the RED and BLUE outfits; sadly, I failed to give team BANANA the YELLOW PANTSUIT outfit - they would have killed it, but whatever. Team BANANA's ADAM and BAILEY have the items for the RED outfit, but BAILEY does not have the BANDANNA for the BLUE outfit; let's not let a bandanna get in the way to team BANANA so we need a query to return just:

```
BANANA BAILEY BLUE BANDANNAS
```

To find the number of items in an outfit:

```
SELECT
  o.name
, count(*) AS "number of items"
FROM
  outfit_item i
, outfit o
WHERE
  i.outfit_id = o.id
GROUP BY
  i.outfit_id
, o.name

  name  | number of items 
--------+-----------------
 RED    |               2
 BLUE   |               2
 YELLOW |               1
```

Similarly, the number of members in a team:

```
SELECT
  t.name
, count(*) AS "number of members"
FROM
  team_member m
, team t
WHERE
  m.team_id = t.id
GROUP BY
  m.team_id
, t.name

  name  | number of members 
--------+-------------------
 BANANA |                 2
 APPLE  |                 3
```

That's all well and good, but how do we combine this information so we can bail BAILEY out of this BANANA blunder?

Comment: Why are there duplicate (member_id, item_id) in MEMBER_ITEM?

Comment: Why are you choosing NOT to use proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax?  And how do you know what outfit Bailey is *supposed* to have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking on board the comment "If any member has an outfit item then all team members must have all items in that outfit" I believe the following will do what you are looking for (I'm using a CTE to work out what outfits are associated with each team).

```
with teamoutfit as (
  -- If any mmber of a team has any part of an outfit then that team is linked to that outfit 
 select distinct te.id as team_id, oft.id as outfit_id from
  team te 
  inner join team_member tm on tm.team_id = te.id
  inner join member_item mi on mi.member_id = tm.id
  inner join outfit_item oi on oi.id = mi.item_id
  inner join outfit oft on oft.id = oi.outfit_id
) 
select te.name as team, tm.name as member, of.name as outfit, oi.name as item from 
team te 
inner join team_member tm on tm.team_id = te.id
inner join teamoutfit tof on tof.team_id = tm.team_id
inner join outfit of on of.id = tof.outfit_id
inner join outfit_item oi on tof.outfit_id = oi.outfit_id
left join member_item mi on oi.id = mi.item_id and tm.id = mi.member_id
where 
mi.member_id is null
```

Output:

```
|   team | member | outfit |     item |
|--------|--------|--------|----------|
| BANANA | BAILEY |   BLUE | BANDANNA |
```

I setup a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/54f40/29) you can use to play with this (and perhaps clarify your question if I misunderstood what you are trying to do).

Comment: It is probably not well-motivated in this example but in the motivating problem, the team is important. The `CROSS JOIN` is not a valid assumption; I updated the question to hopefully clarify that and added your SQL from the fiddle -- thank you for that!!!

Comment: So do you know which outfit each team has selected (not shown in the current data model - would need to add `outfit_id` to `team`) or is it just critical that each team has all of the items within one of the outfits? If its the former then my query can be easily updated (another join condition); the later would require some more info. Will update my sample to show this (without changing the table structure)

Comment: The latter; the only tie between a team and an outfit is the member being tied to an item. If one member has an outfit item, the rest of the outfits items are required and the rest of team members must also have the outfit items.

Comment: OK - that is fairly simple to work out; answer updated.

Comment: You're right -- sorry -- I mixed the item number with the outfit number....updating the question now.

Comment: After correcting the data and updating your fiddle your solution yields the correct answer! Thank you! I've updated your answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Confirmed to work on postgres, albeit not pretty and am 85% sure this can be simplified. Also, I was a little confused on how outfit and outfit_item tables are related. In the way you laid out the tables, bandanas and hats are are always blue, pantsuits are always yellow and shorts/shirts are always red when you join outfit to outfit_item (outfit.id = outfit_item.outfit_id). The test data and query has been written with that understanding.

```
    select distinct 
    tm.name as member_name,
    t.name as team_name,
    o.name as outfit_color, 
    oi.name as outfit_item
    from team_member tm
    join team t 
        on t.id = tm.team_id
    join member_items mi 
        on mi.member_id = tm.id
    join(
        with outfit_item_count as
            (SELECT outfit_id, count(*) AS items 
            FROM outfit_items 
            GROUP BY 1)
        select mi.member_id, oi.outfit_id, oic.items as items_needed, count(mi.item_id) as member_item_count 
        from member_items mi
        join outfit_items oi on oi.id = mi.item_id
        join outfit_item_count oic on oic.outfit_id = oi.outfit_id
        group by 1,2,3)z 
        on z.member_id = tm.id
    join outfit_items oi 
        on oi.outfit_id = z.outfit_id
    join outfit o 
        on o.id = oi.outfit_id
    where z.items_needed > z.member_item_count
    and oi.id not in (select item_id from member_items)
```

Comment: Hmm -- I had to make a few edits for table names but I get no results returned instead of the one line.